# Issue on my Wordpress Site with the footer.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, typeerror, fatal-error

I used a debug and I get the following error: PHP Fatal error Uncaught TypeError: ceil(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/ark/footer.php:20

The line reads like this:

```
$linkOffsetSM = ceil( ffThemeOptions::getQuery('layout')->getWithoutComparationDefault('smoothscroll-sharplink-offset-sm', '') );
```

The full div:

```
<div
        class="hidden smoothscroll-sharplink"
        data-speed="<?php echo absint( ffThemeOptions::getQuery('layout')->getWithoutComparationDefault('smoothscroll-sharplink-speed', 1000) ); ?>"

        <?php

            $linkOffsetXS = ceil( ffThemeOptions::getQuery('layout')->getWithoutComparationDefault('smoothscroll-sharplink-offset', 0) );
            if ( empty($linkOffsetXS) ){
                $linkOffsetXS = 0;
            }

            $linkOffsetSM = ceil( ffThemeOptions::getQuery('layout')->getWithoutComparationDefault('smoothscroll-sharplink-offset-sm', '') );
            if ( empty($linkOffsetSM) ){
                $linkOffsetSM = $linkOffsetXS;
            }

            $linkOffsetMD = ceil( ffThemeOptions::getQuery('layout')->getWithoutComparationDefault('smoothscroll-sharplink-offset-md', '') );
            if ( empty($linkOffsetMD) ){
                $linkOffsetMD = $linkOffsetSM;
            }

            $linkOffsetLG = ceil( ffThemeOptions::getQuery('layout')->getWithoutComparationDefault('smoothscroll-sharplink-offset-lg', '') );
            if ( empty($linkOffsetLG) ){
                $linkOffsetLG = $linkOffsetMD;
            }

        ?>

        data-offset-xs="<?php echo $linkOffsetXS; ?>"
        data-offset-sm="<?php echo $linkOffsetSM; ?>"
        data-offset-md="<?php echo $linkOffsetMD; ?>"
        data-offset-lg="<?php echo $linkOffsetLG; ?>"
    ></div>
```

I'm a novice at best with this.  The footer.php is messing up my margins on my site.  When the file is deleted the site displays perfectly but without a footer.  Need to correct the issue in the footer and I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Declare int to the data before applying ceil:

**Example**

```
$number = function_that_gives_me_a_number();
$ceiled = ceil( (int)$number );
```

In your case:

```
$linkOffsetXS = ffThemeOptions::getQuery('layout')->getWithoutComparationDefault('smoothscroll-sharplink-offset-sm', '');
$linkOffsetXS = ceil( (int)$linkOffsetSM );
```

Do this transformation to all the variables ($linkOffsetXS, $linkOffsetSM, $linkOffsetMD,$linkOffsetLG)

Comment: Hey thanks for your help.  I'm still receiving this: PHP Fatal error Uncaught TypeError: ceil(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/ark/footer.php:20

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: Hey that fixed the formatting so i'll take it!  I do have this showing in the header and just before the footer now though: Deprecated: Required parameter $code follows optional parameter $clientId in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/libsyn-podcasting/admin/lib/Libsyn/Service.php on line 706

Deprecated: Required parameter $postID follows optional parameter $filterOrder in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/ark-core/builder/elements/Portfolio/class.ffElPortfolio.php on line 119

There are four more lines like that but I can't paste because of the character limit.